# Beta function integral appearing in the $O(n)$-model

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

While studying the $O(n)$-model I found myself in the need of integrating
$$\frac{\int_0^{\pi}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}\cos(\theta)^{2r}}{\int_0^\pi\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}},$$
where $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ and $r\in\mathbb{N}$. I imagine however that the author (Brézin, Introduction to Statistical Field Theory) is only considering $n>1$. He claims that this can be done through Beta function integrals. Following his suggestion, I noticed that the integrands are even around $\pi/2$. Then the integral can be reduced to
$$\frac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}\cos(\theta)^{2r}}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}}.$$
We have the [beta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}=B(x,y)=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{2x-1}\cos(\theta)^{2y-1},$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Then the integral I'm looking for is
$$\frac{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{2r-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{2r+n}{2}\right)!}$$
This doesn't seem correct though. All I know is that
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{x^r}{r!}\frac{\int_0^{\pi}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}\cos(\theta)^{r}}{\int_0^\pi\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}}=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{n^r}{2^rr!n(n+2)\cdots(n+2r-2)}x^{2r}.$$
I suspect there is however an error in the book and the correct statement is
$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{(\sqrt{n}x)^r}{r!}\frac{\int_0^{\pi}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}\cos(\theta)^{r}}{\int_0^\pi\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}}=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{n^r}{2^rr!n(n+2)\cdots(n+2r-2)}x^{2r}.$$
This means of course that, the integral I'm looking for equals
$$\frac{\int_0^{\pi}\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}\cos(\theta)^{2r}}{\int_0^\pi\text{d}\theta\sin(\theta)^{n-2}}=\frac{(2r)!}{2^rr!n(n+2)\cdots(n+2r-2)}$$
Can somebody help me understand this integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{2r-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)!}{\left(\frac{n-3}{2}\right)!\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{2r+n}{2}\right)!}
&=\frac{\left(\frac{2r-1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)!}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{2r+n}{2}\right)!}\\
&=\frac{\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)!}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n}{2}+r\right)!}\\
&=\frac{\overbrace{(r-\frac12)(r-\frac32)\dots(\frac32)(\frac12)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}^{(r-\frac12)!}\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)!}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\underbrace{(\frac{n}2+r)(\frac{n}2+r-1)\dots(\frac{n}2+1)(\frac{n}2)\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)!}}_{(\frac{n}2+r)!}\\
&=\frac{(r-\frac12)(r-\frac32)\dots(\frac32)(\frac12)}{(\frac{n}2+r)(\frac{n}2+r-1)\dots(\frac{n}2+1)(\frac{n}2)}\\
&=\frac{(2r-1)(2r-3)\dots(3)(1)}{(n+2r)(n+2r-2)\dots(n+2)(n)}\\
&=\frac{(2r)!}{(2r)(2r-2)\dots(4)(2)(n+2r)(n+2r-2)\dots(n+2)(n)}\\
&=\frac{(2r)!}{2^rr!(n+2r)(n+2r-2)\dots(n+2)(n)}\\
\end{align}$$
Which is the answer required, so you were not wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just got scared by the non integer factorials